# What does this output in syslog mean?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

There is this output every passing minute - one time - in syslog:

CRON[15164]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/test -x /usr/sbin/autodns-dhcp_cron && /usr/sbin/autodns-dhcp_cron)

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 3):

You installed *autodns-dhcp*, a tool that tries to update the DNS record for your computer when you are using DHCP. In that case it is possible that your IP-address changes and so the record would point to a wrong IP address.

The line you showed us does two things:

1. it checks if the file `/usr/sbin/autodns-dhcp_cron` exists (the `/usr/bin/test -x /usr/sbin/autodns-dhcp_cron` part)
2. if it exists it executes that script

Answer (score 1):

It means you have installed "autodns-dhcp".

Package description:

> Description: Automatic DNS updates for DHCP
>
> autodns-dhcp uses bind's dynamic update features to update a zonefile
>   with hostnames from the dhcp leases file, this is done just  once for
>   each hostname as the IP, MAC address and name are settled on the dhcp
>   configuration to have an static zone.